# Kstable not fully correlated with p-value in KS-test

Tags: python, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have done Kolmogorov-Smirnov (ks-test) between 2 groups and I got the following values:

| Description | Kstable | p-val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 0.64091 | 0 |
| A9 | 0.64546 | 0 |
| B67 | 0.74318 | 2.92E-20 |
| B1 | 0.68636 | 2.14E-19 |
| A6 | 0.62046 | 8.55E-15 |
| B1 | 0.61364 | 7.66E-14 |

From what I remember, Kstable score going in a negative correlation with p-value and when it's higher - the pvalue has a lower score.
A1 and A9 has pvalue lower than 2.92E-20 but their kstable is not higher than B67. I thought B67 had fewer patients in the that column, but it wasn't the reason. What could cause a lower Kstable and "greater p-value"?

Comment: Please explain what a "Kstable" is.  If it's a test statistic, then at a minimum you need to report the sample sizes.  Are they all the same or do they differ?

Comment: It's a test statistic value according to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html. The samples are different (n = 32 vs n= 340)

Comment: Differences in sample size alone explain your observations: the p-value depends *strongly* on the sample size.  BTW, I searched your reference for "kstable" but could not find a single instance.

Comment: They related it to "statistic"  I guess it's the test statistic. From previous ks tests I have made, it was always negatively correlated with the p-value but this time there are 2 deviants. At first I thought it's because A1 and A9 groups has multiple "zeros" but it's not the case the "n" is same for all groups